# Does VB.net support EnumerationOptions?

Tags: vb.net, enums

Microsoft documents **EnumerationOptions** at [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumerationoptions?view=netcore-3.1]
and it seems to infer that the VB.Net code below would be acceptable

```
Dim ENumOptions = New System.IO.EnumerationOptions()
```

But it is not! Visual Studio reports **"Type system.io.enumerationoptions is not defined"**
What have I done wrong?

Comment: What .net version are you using?

Comment: How do you plan on using EnumerationOptions?

Comment: You could also try typing `Dim EnumOptions = New EnumerationOptions()`.  It won't compile at first, but IntelliSense will suggest a fix, such as adding the correct namespace either by adding an `Imports` statement or by explicitly typing it out for this line.

Comment: The documentation link you provided is for .NET Core 3.1. Are you targeting .NET Core 3.1? I just created a new Console Application project targeting .NET Core 3.1 and copied your code and it worked without issue. I'm guessing that you're not targeting .NET Core at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing what's happening here is that you want to call `Directory.GetFiles` or the like and you want to do a recursive search without throwing an exception if you hit an inaccessible folder. If you're targeting the .NET Framework then too bad, because you can't. Go [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/) and search for `Directory.GetFiles` filtered by .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET Core 3.1 and you'll see that the overload that uses `EnumerationOptions` is not available in the former.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using below .Net 5 version,

Add reference to  `System.Management`

Then Import.

```
Imports System.Management
```

From .Net 5 it is available in `System.IO`

Comment: That appears to be a significantly different type to the one the OP is trying use.

Comment: Actually a common function used for managing devices.

Comment: `System.Management` is WMI. The `System.IO.EnumerationOptions` class the OP provided the documentation link for is specifically for enumerating files and folders. Take a look at the members for each.

Comment: Never tried. But can't  we achieve with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-tasks--disks-and-file-systems